# IIS7 Integrated Pipeline - Request is not available in this context

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Is there a way to test if the current request (HttpContext.Current.Request) is available in the Application_Error event of the Global.asax when using Integrated Pipeline with IIS7 in ASP.NET? Currently I am using a try-catch, but it seems like there should be a way to verify rather than catching an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe the answer to your question is no. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609512/workaround-for-httpcontext-hiderequestresponse-being-internal-detect-if-httpcont) seems to cover what you're asking. You can use reflection, but it doesn't seem very reliable. Articles like [this blog post](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/11/10/Integrated-mode-Request-is-not-available-in-this-context-in-Application_5F00_Start.aspx) recommend not doing this, and even say:

"Because this event is intended for global initialization activities, any logic that references a specific request is typically a design oversight."

But what does he know about the design of your site, amirite? Your only choice if you really want this is to go back down to Classic.