# How to avoid a HttpException when calling HttpContext.Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

So [HttpContext.Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws if called within a global start

```
public HttpRequest get_Request()
{
    if (this.HideRequestResponse)
    {
        throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("Request_not_available"));
    }
    return this._request;
}
```

This is actually documented

> ASP.NET will throw an exception if you try to use this property when the HttpRequest object is not available. For example, this would be true in the Application_Start method of the Global.asax file, or in a method that is called from the Application_Start method. At that time no HTTP request has been created yet.

Is there a way of checking if a HttpContext.Request is in a state that it can be retrieved without throwing the exception? Effectively I want to write a `TryGetRequest` helper method.

- Reflection is not an option. It needs to be a public API.
- I dont have access to the application context. this is generic logging code. So setting some flag when startup has finished is not an option

Comment: Why are you trying to access the http request in the global asax Applciation_Start in the first place? I think it gets initialized post a particular event in the HttpApplication instance, [BeginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @deostroll he's not trying to access it, he's an external library and doesn't **know** anything about where it's being called from

Comment: Then I guess the only cue here is to maintain some state which signals BeginRequest has happened,  and then try to access the required object. Of course some idea regarding the general goal of the library could help in understanding the requirement better.

Comment: @deostroll **this is generic logging code. So setting some flag when startup has finished is not an option**. it's just a pretty tough scenario, no easy ways to accomplish it.

Comment: @deostroll here u go https://github.com/MindscapeHQ/raygun4net/issues/125

Comment: @deostroll but in this case "the goal of the library" is irrelevant to the question

Comment: I am not sure how that `SetHttpDetails` is getting called in the `Application_Start`. But the context passed to it doesn't have the `Request` (i.e. HttpContext.Current.Request) property set. This is expected behaviour. Every code executed doesn't mean it will have a `HttpContext.Current.Request` instance. You just need a different "kind" of logging. One that logs details of a http request, and one that doesn't.

Comment: Did you read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2609512/685760). It seems similar to yours but with an accepted answer I'm not sure you'll be happy with :(. It does make mention of some work around though.

Comment: This sounds like a (don't shoot the messenger, I didn't call it this) [Boneheaded Exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) which are  your own darn fault, you could have prevented them and therefore they are bugs in your code.  The [ASP.Net pipe line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb470252(v=vs.100).aspx) is very well documented, including when the [Request is created and available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: @ErikPhilips as stated this is from a library context and the idea is to avoid the library being any more intrusive than needed

Comment: Can you check `(HTTPContext.Current == null)` ?

Comment: @DavidCrowell nope. at the time it is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible without using reflection

Answer (score 7):

As *deostroll* observed, it is reasonable and may in fact be necessary to rely on the ASP.NET application lifecycle to determine when the current HttpRequest has become available.  The generic logging code is presumably dependent at the very least on `HttpContext.Current` or some other reference to the current `HttpContext` instance.  If that assumption holds true, then an `HttpModule` can be implemented that stores a flag in the `HttpContext.Items` collection when the `BeginRequest` event fires.  The static `TryGetRequest` helper method can test for the presence of that flag to determine whether it is safe to use `HttpContext.Request`.

Perhaps like this:

```
public class HttpRequestHelper : IHttpModule
{
    private const string HttpRequestIsAvailable = "HttpRequestIsAvailable";

    public static bool TryGetRequest(HttpContext context, out HttpRequest request)
    {
        request = null;
        if (context != null)
        {
            if (context.Items.Contains(HttpRequestIsAvailable))
                request = context.Request;
        }
        return (request != null);
    }

    #region IHttpModule

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
    }

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Items.Add(HttpRequestIsAvailable, true);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The module must be registered in web.config (assuming IIS 7.0 integrated pipeline):

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HttpRequestHelper" type="Utility.HttpRequestHelper" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

The logging code would use the helper method like this:

```
HttpRequest request;
if (HttpRequestHelper.TryGetRequest(HttpContext.Current, out request))
    LogWithRequest(request, message);
else
    LogWithoutRequest(message);
```

The implementation does not rely on private API's or reflection.  It relies on a flag, but the state information remains with the `HttpContext` instance and is well encapsulated.

Comment: I don't know how this will be helpful at all, if HttpContext.Current itself is null, what are you going to do?

Comment: Application_Start, Application_End, and Session_End are all affected. This doesn't address the latter two.

Comment: @AkashKava, if you accept the premise of the question, that generic logging code may call it at any time, then yes, `HttpContext.Current` may be null.  The helper returns `false` and a `null` value for this case.

Comment: @MichaelLiu, in the ASP.NET application life cycle, the `HttpContext` instance is created per request.  Application_Start, Application_End and Session_End occur independently of any request and there is no context.  These cases are all handled by the test for null context.

Answer (score 2):

Why not wrap the call to `HttpContext.Request` with a try, catch block then you can catch the exception and modify your behaviour accordingly.

Comment: because this still actually throws the exception. even if it is handled it it explicitly what i am trying to avoid by asking this question

Comment: Why do you want to avoid throwing the Exception?

Comment: exceptions are expensive and it make it a pain to debug when people have "break on all exceptions" turned on

Comment: @Simon Fair enough, never thought of it like that before. +1

Comment: @Simon You could use [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid debugger to stop at places in code you don't want it to stop